# Silverstripe: delete related dataobjects when deleting with button from a gridfield

Tags: silverstripe

I dont know if it's possible, but is there a way to extend the delete button from a GridField? I've google it and I found nothing.

[image]

I want to add a delete function to another dataobject containing something I want to delete.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to do. Are you trying add another delete button somewhere in the CMS? Or are you trying call some custom code when a custom `DataObject `is deleted? If it's the latter you can add an [`onBeforeDelete`](//api.silverstripe.org/3.3/class-DataObject.html#_onBeforeDelete) function to your `DataObject`.

Comment: Hi 3dgoo. Sorry for my bad english. I'm not trying to add another button. I want to use the delete action button not only the DataObject affected. Example : I a have a DataObject into ModelAdmin, I have a record that I want to delete, I click on delete, ok for this step. But more for that action, I want to delete this DataObjectID from another DataObject that is related. Is it more clearer? If not I will post some codes. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post more code, but you can, as 3dgoo stated, use `onBeforeDelete()` (see http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-DataObject.html#_delete) on the class you want to delete, which takes care of cleaning up other stuff you want to erase.

Comment: @NewbieSSProgrammer What happened to your other question? Why did you delete it?

Comment: @bummzack I've found my solution lately... Answering my own question, I dont think that will be useful when people doesn't understand my question.

Comment: @wmk Oh I doesnt know onBeforeDelete... I will get it a try in few hours. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: It works! thanks @wmk

Comment: @NewbieSSProgrammer: of course you can answer your own questions if you find a solution, maybe it's useful for someone else in future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @3dgoo stated, you can delete related stuff in the `onBeforeDelete()` ([api docs](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.3/class-DataObject.html#_onBeforeDelete)) method.

```
$has_one = [
    'Foo' => 'SomeDataobject'
];

/**
 * gets called before this item is finally deleted,
 * deletes the related "SomeDataObject" also
 */
public function onBeforeDelete()
{
    if ($this->FooID) {
        $this->Foo()->delete();
    }
}
```